# Regarding multiple linear models simultaneously

Tags: r

I am trying to run many linear regressions models simultaneously. Please help me to make a code for this.

I am working on two data frames. In first data frame have 100 dependent variables and in second data frame i have 100 independent variables. Now I want simple linear models like

```
lm1 <- lm(data_frame_1[[1]] ~ data_frame_2[[1]])
lm2 <- lm(data_frame[[2]] ~ data_frame[[2]])
```

and so on .That means I have to run 100 regression models. I want to do this simultaneously. Please help me to make respective codes to run these all models simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks Rui Barradas

Answer (score 0):

It is not that clear what you mean by simultaneously. But maybe doing a loop is fine in your case?

```
model.list = list()
for (i in 1:100){
  model.list[[i]] = lm(data.frame.1[[i]] ~ data.frame2[[i]])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dataframe_1` and `dataframe_2` defined in the Note at the end we define a function `LM` that takes an x name and y name and performs a regression of y on x using the columns from those data frames.  The result is a list of `lm` objects.  Note that the Call: line in the output of each output list component correctly identifies which columns were used.

```
LM <- function(xname, yname) {
  fo <- formula(paste(yname, "~", xname))
  do.call("lm", list(fo, quote(cbind(dataframe_1, dataframe_2))))
}
Map(LM, names(dataframe_1), names(dataframe_2))
```

giving:

```
$x1

Call:
lm(formula = y1 ~ x1, data = cbind(dataframe_1, dataframe_2))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1  
     3.0001       0.5001

... etc ...
```

### Note

Using the builtin `anscombe` data frame define `dataframe_1` as the x columns and data_frame_2 as the y columns.

```
dataframe_1 <- anscombe[grep("x", names(anscombe))]
dataframe_2 <- anscombe[grep("y", names(anscombe))]
```

Comment: Thanks G.Grothendieck